# How do I make a live USB with a binary file?

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb, chromebook, chromeos

I'm running Ubuntu on a Parrot Chromebook and I would like to install ChromeOS to an SD card so I can boot from it when I want but all the other tutorials I'm reading result in installing ChromeOS to the hard drive, which I *do not* want; I like ChromeOS and it definitely has its uses but Ubuntu is so much better all-around.

Comment: [Create a Chromixium USB or DVD from the ISO](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QUR035slylelhUD1o7NA_QbgETu_5l8N05n20IXCn60) using UNetbootin from the default Ubuntu repositories. Chromixium is a Linux distribution designed to look like ChromeOS which is the default operating system on Chromebooks.

Answer (score 0):

Well make a chrome OS bootable USB, and change the booting order in bios to boot your USB first. Then on booting you will see chrome os loading. First time it will show up with set up wizard but won't install it in your hdd and  latter you will see login screen next time boot onwards. You can use this same USB in anywhere to boot chrome os.

**Making USB a ChromeOS bootable**

**Linux :** You can use dd command as follows :

*Note: here in command, you need to give your correct USB device in "of=/dev/sd#"  say "of=/dev/sdb". So beware using it, if you gave wrong device like your hdd - it can overwrite it.*

`dd if=image.img of=/dev/sd# bs=4M`

**Windows :** Use DiskImager like software to make a bootable USB of chrome os.